# How do I generate an Asset URL inside of a ScriptTag?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

My Shopify App is creating a [ScriptTag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-04) when the app is installed. When the script tag is loaded in the store (each time a customer visits), I was hoping to be able to fetch an asset's public url from the client-side JavaScript.

Since the ScriptTag is executed onload, something like this does not seem to work:

`var assetPath = "{{ 'my-test-file.css' | asset_url }}"`

Are there any alternative methods available to generate an asset url from the JavaScript file that is loaded on the client? Or is my only option to fetch this public URL from the [Asset API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/asset?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-04#index-2020-04) using my backend?

Comment: You would have to use the Asset API. Check a workaround using Liquid code snippet in my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555070/2803788).

Comment: @BilalAkbar I figured as much but thought I would ask anyway. Thanks for the help!