# Shopify get meta field value of product using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, getjson

I've been exploring and testing for hours how to retrieve the metafield values from a specific product handle.

I've tested using AJAX calls and using getJSON neither of which have had any success with all seem to throw the same error.

I'm aware that you most definitely can't access the product metafields directly as they're somewhat protected and therefore are excluded from the usual handle.js file I'm currently successfully able to get.

I am seeking someones help to essentially point me in the direction of how to accomplish what I'm looking for.

**product-view.js file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js").done(function() {
        createProductData();
    });
});

function createProductData() {
    $(".product-view").click(function () {
        if ($('#product-view').length == 0){
            $("body").append('<div id="product-view"></div>');
        }

        var product_handle = $(this).data('handle');

        $('#product-view').addClass(product_handle);

        //Default Product Fields
        jQuery.getJSON('/products/' + product_handle + '.js', function (product) {
            var images = product.images;
            var title = product.title;
            var price = product.price;
            var desc = product.description;
        });

        //Product Meta Fields
        jQuery.getJSON('/products/' + product_handle + '?view=metafields.json', function (product) {
            var dish_type = product.metafields.arena.dish;
            console.log(dish_type);
            //error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arena')
        });
    });
}
```

**product.metafields.liquid file**

```
{% layout none %}
{{ product.metafields.arena | json }}
```

Comment: You can output the Metafields value to JS and just read it on frontend. [Metafields value in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555070/2803788)

Comment: @BilalAkbar this is not helpful, the user is trying to create an app that uses global metafields hence the shop reference over product. I'm trying to pull product metafields on a page that isn't the single product page I don't believe your example works for this.

Comment: do you already know the product handle in liquid before page load or you find this information later in JS once page is loaded ?

Comment: @BilalAkbar on click of the button it gets the product handle from the button data-handle attribute which all works as expected as im able to get the title price etc. that comes from the product object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to find a website finally that used what they described as a 'hack' because they don't believe this is the way that `{% capture %}` however, it did achieve the require outcome that I needed and hopefully is useful for others in future:

**theme.liquid file**

```
{% capture 'dishMetaFields' %}
    {
        {% for product in collections["all-dishes"].products %}

            "{{ product.handle }}" : {
                product_chinese_title : "{{product.metafields.arena.chinese_title}}",
                product_feeds : "{{product.metafields.arena.feeds}}",
                product_spice_level : "{{product.metafields.arena.spice}}",
                product_dish : "{{product.metafields.arena.dish}}",
                product_proteins : "{{product.metafields.arena._proteins}}",
                product_diet : "{{product.metafields.arena._diet}}",
                product_cooking_time : "{{product.metafields.arena._diet}}",
                product_cooking_video : "{{product.metafields.arena._method_video}}",
                product_cooking_text : "{{product.metafields.arena._method}}",
                product_nutrients : "{{product.metafields.arena._nutrition}}",
                product_allergies : "{{product.metafields.arena._allergies}}",
                {% unless product.metafields.arena._bundle_dishes == blank %}
                    {%- assign dishCounter = 1 -%}
                    product_bundle_dish : {
                        {% for value in product.metafields.arena._bundle_dishes %}
                            "dish-{{ dishCounter }}" : "{{ value }}",
                            {%- assign dishCounter = dishCounter | plus:1 -%}
                        {% endfor %}
                    }
                {% endunless %}
            },
        
        {% endfor %}
    }
{% endcapture %}

<script type = "text/javascript">
  let dishMetaFields = {{ dishMetaFields }}
</script>
```

You can then access the `dishMetaFields` from the javascript file you're using to access the product object to get the defined metafields should the handles match.

**product-view.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js").done(function() {
        createProductData();
    });
});

function createProductData() {
    $(".product-view").click(function () {
        if ($('#product-view').length == 0){
            $("body").append('<div id="product-view"></div>');
        }

        var product_handle = $(this).data('handle');

        $('#product-view').addClass(product_handle);

        jQuery.getJSON('/products/' + product_handle + '.js', function (product) {
            //Default Product Fields
            var images = product.images;
            var title = product.title;
            var price = product.price;
            var desc = product.description;

            //Product Meta Fields
            var metafields = dishMetaFields[product_handle];
            var dish_type = metafields.product_dish;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the same for cart data?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this following your initial approach. In this scenario, you don't need to iterate over all metafields of a collection but only for the required product. This should be better comparatively in terms of performance. The idea is same, that you generate the JSON object in Liquid snippet and then parse the JSON in JavaScript.

```
{% layout none %}
{
    "product_chinese_title" : "{{product.metafields.arena.chinese_title}}",
    "product_feeds" : "{{product.metafields.arena.feeds}}",
    "product_spice_level" : "{{product.metafields.arena.spice}}",
    "product_dish" : "{{product.metafields.arena.dish}}",
    "product_proteins" : "{{product.metafields.arena._proteins}}",
    "product_diet" : "{{product.metafields.arena._diet}}",
    "product_cooking_time" : "{{product.metafields.arena._diet}}",
    "product_cooking_video" : "{{product.metafields.arena._method_video}}",
    "product_cooking_text" : "{{product.metafields.arena._method}}",
    "product_nutrients" : "{{product.metafields.arena._nutrition}}",
    "product_allergies" : "{{product.metafields.arena._allergies}}"
    {% unless product.metafields.arena._bundle_dishes == blank %}
        ,
        {%- assign dishCounter = 1 -%}
        "product_bundle_dish" : {
            {% for value in product.metafields.arena._bundle_dishes %}
                "dish-{{ dishCounter }}" : "{{ value }}"
                 {% if forloop.last == false %}
                    ,
                 {% endif %}
                 {%- assign dishCounter = dishCounter | plus:1 -%}
            {% endfor %}
                    }
    {% endunless %}
}
```

And for JavaScript part, use simple GET and then parse the response.

```
jQuery.get('/products/' + product_handle + '?view=metafield', function (product) {
  console.log(product)
  console.log(JSON.parse(product))         
});
```

Comment: I tested your code and it throws ```Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0``` just as a heads up

Comment: This works fine for me, but I don't have all these metafields on my tests store. Even if there is some error, it is most probably due to invalid JSON for some missing comma or something that you can fix if you use this code.

Comment: I revisited your code the reason it says unexpected token is because you're getting a HTML page and trying to parse as a JSON when ```console.log``` of product displays the page html so it's clearly not working correctly unfortunately.

Comment: If you look at this sample url from my test store, it generates the JSON and no other HTML. Thatswhy, I am parsing the response as JSON. [Sample URL](https://dev-04.myshopify.com/products/zipped-jacket?view=metafield)